# How to enable keyboard backlight in MSI GE 76 Raider 11UE?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, backlight, msi

I'm running 22.04 on a MSI GE76 Raider 11UE. The keyboard backlight is disabled as soon as the kernel loads. It works just fine in Windows and in the GRUB boot menu, and shows up in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1038:113a SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries KLC
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a67:8517 Medeli Electronics Co., Ltd USB AUDIO
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. AX210 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 5986:1160 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1038:113e SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries ALC
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried `msi-keyboard` as suggested in similar questions for other models, but I get this error:

```
cannot open usb device
```

Open RGB fails to detect the keyboard, and I don't want to mess around since it's been known to brick some hardware.

*I should also note that the function keys for the keyboard backlight do not work with Ubuntu. Other function keys do work for the most part, except for those tied to Windows-only software (such as the key to launch the MSI Center).*

Any clue what I should do here?

**Update:**
Still no keyboard light, but I've made some progress after following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/ToadKing/26c28809b8174ad0e06bfba309cf3ff3). I used Wine Staging and the system tray icon works perfectly. I can now modify my light bar, but still no dice with the keyboard.

I have a hunch that it may simply need the correct udev rule, but I'm not a device specialist, so I don't want to mess around with what I don't know. Would be grateful if anyone has any clue how to proceed there. The linked guide should be helpful in that sense, and I can provide any info needed to help figure this one out.

I believe msi-keyboard din't work because it's a per-key device.

This program: https://github.com/Askannz/msi-perkeyrgb could possibly work, but it's unmaintained (so it seems), and it's just a bunch of us in the issues trying to help each other out with tidbits.

However, I believe with the right settings, it might be possible to use it.

Update #2:

For a brief time, it worked! I don't know what made it work, but here's what I'd done up until this point:

Followed this guide: https://gist.github.com/ToadKing/26c28809b8174ad0e06bfba309cf3ff3

- Seems to be written by a Steelseries dev, and allowed msi-perkeyrgb to work, sort of (more on this in a bit).

I am able to modify the bar at the front (though, the Steelseries software itself is flaky, even in Windows, and after some playing around, it turned the bar off completely (the device wouldn't even show up in `lsusb`), so I recommend leaving well alone.

It's working again after an update to the software on the Windows side, but there's a duplicate (unplugged) device showing up in Windows now (which may be my fault after trying some `msi-perkeyrgb` settings. At least `lsusb` once again shows the correct list.

When it did work, briefly, the function keys worked as they should - hold the function key, and the available functions lit up red. I couldn't seem to adjust the brightness, but I may have been missing it because I was in bright sunlight at the time.

Also of note: using the correct device combo with the `--id` flag on `msi-perkeyrgb` works for changing the bar at the front, AND for setting the keyboard to a preset. HOWEVER, the keyboard will only blink on when coming out of suspend, or turning the computer on initially. The moment the kernel loads, it turns right back off.

I know this is a long shot, but I'm leaving this question open in case others come across it and we can work toward a solution. It's already coming up in the first page on Google when you look for this issue, so hopefully we might be able to build some traction.

I've also checking out [the projects Rinzwind mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417036/1992). So far, no dice, but I'll be keeping an eye on this one. I just recommend NOT trying anything risky.

Comment: Do check for any BIOS/firmware updates for your machine.  My MSI GP66 Leopard 11ux uses the 1038:1122 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries KLC keyboard and the lights worked with Ubuntu 22.04 out of the box. Brightness changes only happen after releasing the fn key.  Haven't done much else with them.

Comment: @ubfan1 sure thing. I did have an update for the SteelSeries firmware (on Windows) recently, but it didn't change anything under Ubuntu. Hopefully things will change in future updates without me doing anything, because I really don't like the idea of bricking something just to get lights on.

Answer (score 2):

Short version specific to this question:

- There is no support for the GS76 (yet) so there will not be an answer in the form of a command to issue.

I see 2 possible ways to go:

- OpenRGB is the most active but your system is not included in their devices list yet. So I would suggest creating a [ticket](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues) (there is already one for a GS66 but it is incomplete)
- [MSIKLM](https://github.com/Gibtnix/MSIKLM) is active too; package is 8 months old but their issues page is active. On their project page are people mentioning a GS66 and a GS76 as working partially with a remark that you might need to find the correct commands using Windows, [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) and USBpcap to get it working.

---

Long version; a bit more generic:

OpenRGB. In case anyone else faces the same problem you can install it using ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/openrgb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openrgb
```

There is a device id list for working MSI products for vendor id 1462 = MSI Mysticlight                                              :

```
3ea4
4459
1720
7b10 7b12 7b17
7b85 
7b93 7b94 7b96
7c34 7c35 7c36 7c37
7c42
7c56 7c59
7c60 7c67
7c70 7c71 7c73 7c75 7c76 7c77 7c79
7c80 7c81 7c82 7c83 7c84 7c85 7c86 7c87 7c88 7c89
7c90 7c91 7c92 7c94 7c95 7c96 7c98 7c99
7d06 7d07 7d09 
905d
```

and for vendor id 1770 (MSI/SteelSeries 3-Zone Laptop Keyboard) there is also `ff00`.

- for anyone not using MSI: check the link for your vendor id and product id.
- There is also a [supported device list](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/wikis/Supported-Devices)

I agree that this is likely not yet to work for you. I would suggest to open a [ticket](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues) asking for support. From the reactions they look like very active. [Here](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/issues/2525) is the request for the GE66 so very close to your GE76 but it is still incomplete.

> I have a hunch that it may simply need the correct udev rule

It wont be simple and it will be "dev rules". OpenRGB has this listed [udev documentation page](https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB/-/releases/release_0.7#Linux-64-bit) but it is for all systems they support and you would need it for one device but I agree it is pretty daunting.

---

Regarding msi-perkeyrgb: it is indeed dead but if you have a supported board the software will work. Looks like yours is not though but it might help other users.

There is also a MSI-RGB project and that one is dead too and also supports only a limited amount of older MSI boards. If someone owns such a board go for it.

[MSIKLM](https://github.com/Gibtnix/MSIKLM) though is more current (8 months old but their board is still active) and seems more generic as they do not list models but state:

> General
>
> The MSI Keyboard Light Manager (MSIKLM) is an easy-to-use tool that allows to configure the SteelSeries keyboards of MSI gaming notebooks with Linux / Unix in almost the same way as the SteelSeries Engine can do using Windows.

and there is [someone](https://github.com/Gibtnix/MSIKLM/issues/46) with a GS76 that has it working with issues. There is a mentioning of using Windows, [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) and USBpcap to get the correct commands in there and [here](https://github.com/Gibtnix/MSIKLM/issues/42) for a GS66. So if you like an adventure you should get it working that way. It might be an idea to create a ticket here too seeking help in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands in **terminal**:
To turn **on** the leds type:
`xset led on`

To turn **off** the leds type:
`xset led off`

If it does work you can add the command to auto execute everytime you login into OS.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With **xmodmap** you can set options according to your keyboard **see help**, type:

```
xmodmap --help
```

To see **all buttons** that can be set for turning on the leds, type:

```
xmodmap -pm
```

For example to set the **Scroll Lock button** to turn on the leds, type:

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

*Now by pushing the **Scroll Lock** should **turn on** the leds.*

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. How would this enable the LEDs? Isn't this just remapping keys?

Comment: And, supposing this works, how would I set it so that <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> does that function, as it is supposed to?